# Is there a Windows 10 Client image for docker?

Tags: virtualization, docker

I know there are **Server** Base Images [on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-base-os-images), but I am not looking for a server image.  I am trying to run windows 10 client containers on windows server 2016.  Are there any client base images that maybe I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

The official Windows base image for containers can be found in the Docker Hub under
[Windows](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows).

However, this image has very negative reviews, and must be executed on Windows
of exactly the same version.

For example, pulling version 1903:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903
```

is supposed to work only on Windows version 1903, although I haven't tried it.

Comment: Yeah I know those are on Docker Hub, but what I am asking is if there are **CLIENT** images on docker hub or somewhere else floating around.  The ones on Docker Hub are server images which are drastically different at the core level.  I appreciate you trying to help though!

Comment: The don't think Microsoft publishes client versions. I believe they never got working the GUI in docker for that. Maybe in the future, but for now that's all you can get.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc.  I appreciate your help!